# problem with mnotes package

Tags: errors, marginnote

I'd like to test the `mnotes` package but it does not seem to work.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mnotes}

\begin{document}
dummy text\MNOTE{text}
\end{document}
```

The user manual states that you need to use `\usepackage{mnote}` to use the package, but if you do that pdftex complains about a missing `.sty`

Changing the argument to `mnotes` removes the missing `.sty` error, but then an undefined control sequence appears. What should I do?

Comment: @all isn't there a "bug" tag?

Comment: No, there isn't. Please, file a bug report to the package author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missing `\fi` in the sty file.

In line 65ff you will find:

```
\if@twocolumn\if@mnotes@scale\hoffset\pdfpagewidth
    \advance\hoffset-\paperwidth
    \hoffset.5\hoffset\fi
```

correct is:

```
\if@twocolumn\if@mnotes@scale\hoffset\pdfpagewidth
    \advance\hoffset-\paperwidth
    \hoffset.5\hoffset\fi\fi%<-added a \fi
```

---

In my opinion this is the result of bad structuring code. For me the correct way is:

```
\if@twocolumn
  \if@mnotes@scale
    \hoffset\pdfpagewidth
    \advance\hoffset-\paperwidth
    \hoffset.5\hoffset
  \fi
\fi%<-added a \fi
```